# how to get totalTime in Flex spark videoPlayer?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

It seems totalTime is missing in spark videoPlayer

**How can I retrieve the length of a movie in s:videoPlayer component ?**

(it also seems onMetaData is missing)

regards

Answer (score 2):

Via [duration](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VideoPlayer.html#duration) property: duration of the video's playback, in seconds.